# highlight active element based on active page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I searched for similar questions but none worked so I'm here requesting your help.
**What I want is:**

When someone visits "about" the li will become active so that css will apply. When he presses on "service" the same as above will happen etc.

**Note 1:** this menu is called in the main body with require_once("path/to/navmenu.php") and I don't know if it affects anything

**Note 2:** I know jQuery is the key here but i tried some code in stackoverflow from similar questions and none worked. A JSfiddle is appreciated

**HTML CODE:**

```
<nav class="flexy-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">home</a><div  class="menu-space"></div></li>
    <li><a href="about-us-style1.php">about</a><div class="menu-space"></div></li>
    <li><a href="service-style2.php">service</a><div class="menu-space"></div></li>
</nav>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
 .flexy-menu li:hover > a,
 .flexy-menu li.active a {
   background: #c68f50;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: some variation of this might help ? -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755751/how-to-style-a-link-that-matches-the-current-url

Comment: even this could help just with CSS https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using PHP, so you could just define a PHP variable in the head of each page, e.g. for the about page:

`$about_page = 1;`

and then you could highlight your menu-point if the user is on that particular page:

```
<li><a href="about-us-style1.php" class="<?php if($about_page == 1) { echo 'highlighted'; } ?>">about</a><div class="menu-space"></div></li>
```

And don't forget to declare the class `highlighted` in CSS:

```
.highlighted {
   background: #c68f50;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Just an idea - there may be a more advanced solution

Comment: Ahh i see yes. will try it and come back with the results

Answer (score 2):

Well I would appreciate doing it in PHP as you have a seperate file for NavBar and its a good practice. With JQuery it can be achieved as follows:

```
function setMenu()
{
   var chk = false;
   $(".flexy-menu li").removeClass('active').each(function()
   {
       if(chk == false && window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a').attr('href')) != -1)
       {
           $(this).addClass('active');chk = true;
       }
   });       
}
```

You may call `setMenu();` anytime after the menu is displayed. Better to call it in `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: this wont work as anchor link do not have any attribute called `src`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are redirecting your user to another page then you need to do server side code to check for current page and apply appropriate class to link.

But if you not redirecting then let me know I will add code for the same.

// Server Side Code

```
<?php
    $page_name = str_replace('.php', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    $page_array = array(
            'index'=>'',
            'about'=>''
    );
    $page_array[$page_name] = 'active';
?><html>
    <head>
        <title>Active Menu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" class="<?php echo $page_array['index']?>">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="<?php echo $page_array['about']?>">About</a>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

p.s.: I have kept this very simple to make you understand the core concept of what we are trying to achieve. This can be improved in many ways but for the startup guys this can be good help on where to start.

Comment: it's not that they "need" to do server side code. and that isn't an answer to his question. not totally.

Comment: @TheWarlock, actually he wants to redirect page, so that only way is to do server side code to apply class to appropriate link. That is the reason this approach was posted.

Comment: how about a common code of js present in all pages that can evaluate it based on the URL and some prepared data?

Comment: Hello i see what both you mean here.
The easiest task for me is to set a JS in head section that would run in all pages.
Would that be a solution though?
Also i can have different head sections in each page if different code is required.

Comment: Yes that can be done, but would you personally prefer this solution if you are in this situation? So my try was to give him a optimal solution and not just solution.

Comment: Im always open to different solutions and thanks for your insight in my problem. Also could you give me an example of  server side code that checks the url? lets say "if url = index.php then add active class to the corresponding li"

Comment: Thanks for going into the trouble! Will get your code for future referrence

Answer (score 0):

As you are redirecting user. You need to check page name and highlight the `li` element that has an anchor link with the same value as `href` after page is ready. Following snippet might help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pagename = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    $(".flexy-menu li a").each(function (index) {
        if($(this).attr("href").indexOf(pagename)==0){
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is the complete snippet. save this as a html file with name `test2.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .flexy-menu li:hover > a, .flexy-menu li.active a {
         background: #c68f50;
         color: #fff;
    }
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pagename = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    $(".flexy-menu li a").each(function (index) {
        if($(this).attr("href").indexOf(pagename)==0){
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
  <nav class="flexy-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">home</a>

        <div class="menu-space"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="test2.html">about</a>

        <div class="menu-space"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="service-style2.php">service</a>

        <div class="menu-space"></div>
    </li>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice in html first `li` is having active `active` class.  but in browser if the second link will be highlighted (if you save the file as `test2.html`)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! Will add it to my snippet list :)

Answer (score 0):

Well hello again. I run through all of your comments and answers.
EVERYthing you mention is doing the trick to be honest. But since im kinda unfamiliar with JS/Jquery and CSS3 selectors i went the php way :)

So what it did: added a variable on each page like $about_page=1; eg. when someone visits indexpage.
Then on the navigation.php i did some if statement that echos the "active" class. (

```
<li <?php if($about_page==1){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="about-us-style1.php">about</a><div class="menu-space"></div>
            </li>
```