# add class to element based on custom page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Goal: 
I need the element on the menu/nav links to be highlighted based on the current active page. Example - viewing "About" page will highlight the "About" item on the menu.

What I've tried:
[highlight active element based on active page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506846/highlight-active-element-based-on-active-page) made the most sense but:

- It's not adding the class based on page being viewed. I added the variable on the .php template file and the Wordpress page created from dashboard itself but both don't work.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Wordpress Dashboard Page: About
custom template file: About.php

Menu items:

```
<div>
  <a class="(add class here based on page url)">About</a>
  <a class="(add class here based on page url)">Blog</a>
  <a class="(add class here based on page url)">Products</a>
  <a class="(add class here based on page url)">Contact</a>
<div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "it does not work" - what exactly are you doing, what are you expecting, and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below:

```
<?php 
global $post;       
// add 'post_name' to the $post_class                
$post_class = $post->post_name;
?>

<div>
    <a class="<?php echo $post_class; ?>_page">item</a> 
    <a>item</a> 
    <a>item</a> 
    <a>item</a> 
<div>
```

On the **$post_class** you will get the current page name so the class will get based on page name.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is what OP had in mind. I think it's rather one class, but applied to the anchor which corresponds to the current page.

Comment: If your page slug is "about" You will return the class in a like this: about_page